# Angular 4 app not loading via IIS

Tags: angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

I have created angular 4 web ui project using visual studio code. The backend API code is written and use visual studio 2017 for it. When I execute ng serve on the command prompt and type localhost://4200 , the application loads and shows me the home component. But when i try to run the application via IIS, it doesnt load the home component and takes for ever. I can see error message cannot load http://mrdb.com in the debugger tab

The project is configured to run on IIS by setting it up the following way

```
1. The virtual directory points the MRDB.WEB.API  folder
2. The index.html in the web api project  points to a folder called MRDB_Client. It contains files generated by web.ui project. Thats when we run ng build. So it  contains all the angular modules and components to load. The index.html page contains the app-root tag as well.
```

So when I run mrb.com on the browser, it will load the index.html which in turn will look for the appropriate modules and components to be loaded.

I have also made a host file entry for the application.See below

```
127.0.0.1          mrdb.com
```

The binding for the project is set as

[image]

The Advanced setting looks as follows

[image]

The application pool looks as follows

[image]

The index.html in the api project looks as follows

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
        <base href="./" />
        <title>MRDB</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">
        <meta name="keyword" content="MRDB">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="notifyjs-corner"></div>
        <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MRDB_Client/inline.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MRDB_Client/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MRDB_Client/scripts.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MRDB_Client/styles.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MRDB_Client/vendor.bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="MRDB_Client/main.bundle.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**app.module**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpModule} from '@angular/http'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { NavbarComponent } from './navbar/navbar.component';
import { TopbarComponent } from './topbar/topbar.component';
import { FooterbarComponent } from './footerbar/footerbar.component';
import { MRDBGlobalConstants } from './shared/mrdb.global.constants';
import {AppRoutingModule} from './app.routing';
import {HomeComponent} from './home/home.component';
import {MovieComponent} from './movie/movie.component';
import { MRDBCommonService } from './shared/services/mrdb.common.service';
import { NotFoundComponent } from './not-found/not-found.component';
import { SharedModule } from './shared/shared.module';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterbarComponent,
    TopbarComponent,
    NavbarComponent,
    MovieComponent,
    HomeComponent,
    NotFoundComponent  
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    SharedModule,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [MRDBGlobalConstants,
              MRDBCommonService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**app.component**

```
import { Component ,ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'app';

constructor(public viewRef : ViewContainerRef) {

}

}
```

**app.routing module**

```
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {Routes,RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
import {MovieComponent} from '../app/movie/movie.component';
import {HomeComponent}  from '../app/home/home.component';
import {NotFoundComponent} from './not-found/not-found.component';

export const appRoutes:Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'movie', component : MovieComponent},
  {path: '**',component : NotFoundComponent}
];

@NgModule({
imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes,{ useHash: true})],
exports:[RouterModule]

})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**home.component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**Error page**

[image]

I have verified that the connection string is correct in web.config of the webapi project and also amended the app pool identity to contain service account that has permissions on the database which is currently showing ApplicationPoolIdentity in the screenshot below.

Comment: did you check in Developer tools console, if there are any errors? may be path are incorrect?

Comment: I am getting a different error now. it spits the following error on the browser internal error - server connection terminated

Comment: It looks like the application is not hit when invoked in browser.

Comment: I don't see anything happening in the network tab nor console tab. It directly spits out the error message mentioned above in the browser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to resolve. I renamed the host name in IIS as well changed the port number and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Startup.cs file for routing to your defined page while using IIS.